# How do I connect to a DB on one server using an SSH tunnel on another server, in .NET?

Tags: .net, oracle, odp.net, ssh-tunnel, ssh.net

I'm running some code on my local developer machine. I want to access an Oracle database kept on `db-server` using the credentials `db-user`/`db-passwd`, but to do so I need to create an SSH tunnel on `ssh-server` using my credentials `ssh-user`/`ssh-passwd`.

I'm using SSH.NET and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core.

```
        private const string Constr = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=" +
                                      "    (ADDRESS_LIST=" +
                                      "        (ADDRESS=" +
                                      "            (PROTOCOL=TCP)" +
                                      "            (HOST=%%HOST%%)" +
                                      "            (PORT=%%PORT%%)" +
                                      "        )" +
                                      "    )" +
                                      "    (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=DB_SID))" +
                                      ");" +
                                      "User Id=db-user;" +
                                      "Password=db-passwd;";

        public ConnectViaSsh()
        {
            using (var client = new SshClient(ssh-server, ssh-user, ssh-passwd))
            {
                client.Connect();
                if (client.IsConnected)
                {
                    var port = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", 15211, db-server, 1521);
                    client.AddForwardedPort(port);
                    port.Start();

                    var connectionString = Constr
                        .Replace("%%HOST%%", $"{port.BoundHost}")
                        .Replace("%%PORT%%", $"{port.BoundPort}")
                        ;
                    using var conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
                    conn.Open();
                    ...
```

However, for some reason I'm getting an OracleException with ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied.

I know that db-user and db-passwd are correct, as if I copy/paste the values into a Rider Oracle data source and test the connection (also using an SSH tunnel set up in the data source properties) then it succeeds.

Am I somehow inadvertently pointing my Oracle connection at my Oracle database running on localhost:1521? This would explain the invalid credentials exception.

Comment: Oracle is too dumb to lie about that particular error message.  It _is_ returned from a database, so the fact that you received that error is proof that you actually reached _some_ database, _somewhere_.  So there is only one possibility.  You are providing the wrong username/password _for the database you reached_.   We can't even guess which database that is.  It appears from your code that you are supplying host and port via some substitution parameters and we don't know the values of those.

Comment: @EdStevens I know, that's why I'm asking whether I've messed up and accidentally pointed this code at a local Oracle database, where the user db-user with password db-passwd doesn't exist.

Comment: We don't know what you are pointing to. I'm not familiar with the language (Java?) but in your first block of code you specify HOST=%%HOST%%, which looks like a parameter for which we don't know the value.  In your second block of code you specify 'ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", 15211'.  I don't know how that is used, but 127.0.0.1 is the local loopback address.  Network requests to that IP address never leave the requesting client, and are instead , looped back;.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear from the tags (.net, odp.net, ssh.net) that the language is .NET. You don't need to know the values of my DB connection - whether the server I'm connecting to is foo.server.com or bar.server.com is irrelevant. %%HOST%% is visible as a placeholder in Constr, which is shown at the top of the code sample.

Comment: I tend not to notice tags because they get mis-used so often.  If you want help debugging a connection, then yes it is important to know the values - or at least consistently obfuscated values. I had already guessed that %%HOST%% is a placeholder.  You asked "Am I somehow inadvertently pointing my Oracle connection at my Oracle database running on localhost:1521?", Well, the name 'localhost' resolves to ip address 127.0.0.1, and I see that address in your code, which I already pointed out.

Comment: @EdStevens OP replaces the `%%HOST%%` and `%%PORT%%` placeholders with theoretically **dynamic** values of a local port forwarded through SSH to a remote machine. Practically OP hard-codes them to `127.0.0.1:15211` in `ForwardedPortLocal` constructor. That part seem ok to me, unless the local port 15211 is occupied by some other process. It's better no to hard code it – `new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", "db-server", 1521)`

Comment: If you shut down your local database you won't get a ORA-1017 error anymore if it tries to connect there. Have you tried that?

Comment: you should also try `Datasource=server:port/SID`